# On the phase-invariance of vectors in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

One of the postulates of quantum mechanics is that if $\phi$ is a unit vector in some Hilbert space (in the simplest case let's consider $\mathbb{C}$), it describes the same state as $e^{i\theta}\phi$ for any $\theta$. If we picture all these unit vectors as part lying on some circle, does it not follow under this postulate that *all* unit vectors correspond to the same state, since they're only some rotation away from each other?

Comment: What do you mean with "all unit vectors correspond to the same state"? Do you mean every unit vector of a general Hilbert space corresponds to one and only one (the same) state?!

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Yes, which I know is obviously wrong but I am trying to find my error. For example, suppose we have two unit vectors $u, v$. Then since both are unit vectors does it not follow that $u$ is simply some rotation of $v$, and hence the same represent the same state under the postulate?

Comment: No, this does not follow in general. For example, take any two unit vectors which are orthogonal. For $H=\mathbb C$, all unit vectors are related by a rotation. Indeed, the only unit vector up to a phase is $1$. So all vectors with length $1$ are of the form $e^{i\theta} 1$.

Comment: since these are complex vectors there are two angles you may define between them, one is related to the modulus of their correlation, the other is what you described that leads to |correlation| = 1. But the former is not that kind, moreover is independent of such phase.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Sorry I did not completely understand your counterexample. Are you saying that when $H = \mathbb{C}$ there is only one unit vector up to phase difference, but in other Hilbert spaces this does not hold?

Comment: Take e.g. $H=\mathbb C^2$. There are two orthogonal unit vectors, $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$ which are not related by the multiplication of a phase, i.e. there is no $\theta \in \mathbb R$ s.t. $u=e^{i\theta} v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are mixing up the picture of the complex plane as a vector space with the picture of the state space/Hilbert space as a vector space. These are two independent sets of axes. Multiplying a state by any complex number does not change the ray along which the state lies in Hilbert space.

For example, consider a two state system — a spin-1/2 degree of freedom, say — with orthonormal basis vectors $\left|\uparrow\right>$ and $\left|\downarrow\right>$. The two basis vectors correspond to two independent directions in Hilbert space. If you multiply the state $\left|\uparrow\right>$ by any complex number $\alpha$, you get a new vector $\alpha\left|\uparrow\right>$ that still lies along the $\left|\uparrow\right>$-axis in Hilbert space.

To change the direction of your state in Hilbert space, you would need to apply a unitary linear operator that is not a multiple of the identity to your vector. You can think about this as multiplying the vector by a $2\times2$ matrix in the example of the two state system.

As an example, you could apply an operator that takes the state $\left|\uparrow\right>$ to the state $\alpha \left|\uparrow\right> + \beta \left|\downarrow\right>$. Now you've rotated the state in the Hilbert space, and it no longer lies along the $\left|\uparrow\right>$-axis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure I completely understand your example (likely as my knowledge of physics is still pretty elementary), isn't the complex plan itself a Hilbert space, so why would transforming a vector by a complex number not simply rotate it?

Comment: @CBBAM The complex plane is a Hilbert space, but it's not the same Hilbert space that the state vectors live in. Maybe it would help to think of the example of a real vector space, say $\mathbf{R}^3$. The real numbers are a Hilbert space too, but if you multiply a vector in $\mathbf{R}^3$ by a real number, you get another vector along the same direction.

Comment: The imaginary and real axes of the complex plane have nothing to do with the axes in the Hilbert space.

Comment: I think I got it now, in one dimensions all unit vectors are equivalent because you only have one linearly independent vector, but the same cannot be said when the dimension is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in your assumption is that you assumed Hilbert space to be $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}$ is one dimensional complex vector space because any field over itself is one dimensional vector space,that is why applying $e^{i\theta}$ gives you all "unit vectors" because you need only one unit vector to describe one dimensional vector space
For representing higher dimensional Hilbert spaces you need more than just one set of complex numbers.

Comment: Ah I see, so the linear independence of higher dimensions is what answers my confusion.

Comment: Yes, you can have higher dimensional complex vector space by just using more sets of complex number, in that case by applying $e^{i\theta}$ won't generate any new different vectors. For example for complex vector space represented by {$1+i,1+i$} as basis vector, now you apply $e^{i\theta}$ you won't be able to generate vector such as {$1+i,1-i$}, you can only get this vector by using  ($1,-i$) as coefficient of your basis vectors